# ruby on rails bootstrap3 gets applied after html renders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Rails 4 boostrap3 gem installed but when my page loads the html displays then then bootstrap gets applied this happens very quickly on every page load. Why is the style not applied on load of page?

Comment: post your view that has the html and bootstrap

Comment: Happens on all my views.  I am thinking its a config setting somewhere.

Comment: Can you show me how did you config that gem? I think it bases on the position where you place the config lines

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading css and js files in header and they are not loaded asynchroniously.